# Ordered Results Set within a relationship using Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a table structure that has this structure:

`User (has many) Subjects (has many) Modules (has many) Topics (has many) Notes`

I have foreign keys in each table like so:

`Subject (user_id), Modules(subject_id), Topics(module_id), Notes(topic_id)`

I want to have a way to access all the notes created by a user ordered by the date created. Is this possible using the query builder?

**Note.php**

```
class Note extends Model implements SluggableInterface
{

    use SluggableTrait;

    protected $sluggable = [
        'build_from' => ['question', 'id'],
        'save_to'    => 'slug'
    ];
    protected $fillable = ['question', 'answer', 'topic_id'];

    public function topic()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Topic');
    }


}
```

**Topic.php**

```
class Topic extends Model implements SluggableInterface
{

    use SluggableTrait;

    protected $sluggable = [
        'build_from' => ['title', 'id'],
        'save_to'    => 'slug'
    ];
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'module_id'];

    public function notes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Note');
    }

    public function module()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Module');
    }

}
```

Comment: Show us please how you define your relationships "user has many subjects" is enough, because all remaining are same just different models. By inspecting your models we know that relationship is correctly defined. What Laravel are you using? (do retag question please).

Comment: Hi , by define - you mean in the model file (i.e. app/User.php), etc. and I'm using Laravel 5.

Comment: Just post one of your models here thats all. "Yes" is the answer to your question in above comment.

Comment: @Kyslik - thank you, I've done so now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.  If you wish to use your relationships, you will need to nest a few loops to make your way through the entire "tree" of relationships.

```
$user = User::with('subjects.modules.topics.notes')->find($user_id);

$notes = new Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;

foreach($user->subjects as $subject) {
    foreach($subject->modules as $module) {
        foreach($module->topics as $topic) {
            foreach($topic->notes as $note) {
                $notes->add($note);
            }
        }
    }
}

$notes = $notes->sortBy('created_at');
```

As for making it easier through database design, that's a tough question without knowing what the rest of your app is doing.  If this is the only place where you have any notes, then I would say probably it's the ideal solution.  If other places need notes too, then it might be a problem.

Another approach would have to been to use the query builder which wouldn't require you to loop through any result sets but would require you write the sql.  I wouldn't say it's simpler or easier though.

```
$notes = \DB::table('users')
    ->select('notes.*')
    ->join('subjects', 'users.id', '=', 'subjects.user_id')
    ->join('modules', 'subjects.id', '=', 'modules.subject_id')
    ->join('topics', 'modules.id', '=', 'topics.module_id')
    ->join('notes', 'topics.id', '=', 'notes.topic_id')
    ->where('users.id', $user_id)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Perfect! Just for the future, how could I have made this easier for myself through the database design (or was the complication a given?)

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure because of naming conventions:

```
$user = User::with(['subjects.modules.topics.notes' => function($query)
{
    $query->orderBy('created_at')
}])->whereId($user_id)->first();

dd($user);
```

Give me feedback in comments what you get.

Comment: Hi, I get a collection with a User object back, I was looking for the notes by a user ordered by the created date. :)

Comment: Thanks for the help! The guy above answered it :D